# Go Reflect Method Call invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

Tags: reflection, go

I'm trying to use reflect to call a method on a struct. However, I'm getting a `panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference` even though both the `attachMethodValue` and the `args` are non-nil. Any ideas on what it could be?

Go Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/QSVTSkNKam

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "reflect"

type UserController struct {
    UserModel *UserModel
}

type UserModel struct {
    Model
}

type Model struct {
    transactionService *TransactionService
}

func (m *Model) Attach(transactionService *TransactionService) {
    m.transactionService = transactionService
}

type Transactioner interface {
    Attach(transactionService *TransactionService)
}

type TransactionService struct {
}

func main() {
    c := &UserController{}
    transactionService := &TransactionService{}
    valueField := reflect.ValueOf(c).Elem().Field(0) // Should be UserController.UserModel

    // Trying to call this
    attachMethodValue := valueField.MethodByName("Attach")

    // Argument
    args := []reflect.Value{reflect.ValueOf(transactionService)}

    // They're both non-nil
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", attachMethodValue)
    fmt.Println(args)

    // PANIC!
    attachMethodValue.Call(args)

    fmt.Println("The end.")
}
```

Comment: Which line is line 29? Where the code panics

Comment: I would think the problem is in `val := reflect.ValueOf(c.AppController).Elem()`

Comment: Or maybe it's something that happens in the call to `attachMethodValue.Call(args)`. Either way, we'll need the exact location of the error.

Comment: Updated the code, removed dependency on Revel. Now it's simple Go-code, but it's still not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It panics because the UserModel pointer is nil. I think you want:

```
c := &UserController{UserModel: &UserModel{}}
```

[playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/Q-tqPMlv5h)